# New account association & missing reputation from migrated posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-accounts, migrated-questions

I created an account [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/users/84655/barry) earlier today.  When creating my account it correctly associated with my existing accounts and I received a bonus of 100 reputation.

I also received 20 reputation due to two questions being migrated to SuperUser from WebApps that had a single up vote each. So now I have a total of 121 reputation.

Whilst having a look around I noticed that [one of my migrated posts](https://superuser.com/questions/269523/what-are-evernotes-keyboard-shortcuts/269524#269524) was marked as accepted.

The question was migrated from WebApps on Apr 11 (with one up vote) and then marked as accepted on SuperUser on May 3.

I haven't received the 15 reputation for this accepted answer.  I have checked my `/reputation` page and also triggered a rep recalc and it still doesn't appear.

Is this by design or is this a bug?

Comment: Guess you had to be there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed up/improved the way accepts are handled in code so that the 15 rep (the vote and rep) will now go to the answer owner it goes with.  Note this will *not* give the 2 rep to the acceptor (at this time), that's a very different/more expensive hookup compared to what we currently do.

This will be fixed in 2 stages, it'll take the next build to fix the code so the future is all set, then we'll follow that up with a database push that'll fix up history.

All affected users will be recalced when this happens, giving them the accept reputation they were missing.

Comment: So if understand properly, the +2 gets lost. At least this is what happened to me when migrating this question to a site in which I did not have user and eventually created it: From http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/64275/fedorqui?tab=reputation
 to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/41759/fedorqui?tab=reputation